# verifying tinproxy installation through script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, ansible

I am creating proxy in Ubuntu and deployed tinyproxy. Once deployment and configuration is done it has to be restarted. It will output like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.log
INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Creating child number 4 of 10 ...
INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Creating child number 5 of 10 ...
INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Creating child number 6 of 10 ...
INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Creating child number 7 of 10 ...
INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Creating child number 8 of 10 ...
INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Creating child number 9 of 10 ...
INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Creating child number 10 of 10 ...
INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Finished creating all children.
INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Setting the various signals.
INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Starting main loop. Accepting connections
```

This is successful scenario. I need verify output using shell script that it has installed properly. I can see this installation is successful. Any suggestion to verify this as successful installation?
**UPDATE:**
It has to be implement through ansible. I tried following

```
- name: Restarting tinyporxy
  service: name=tinyproxy state=restarted

- name: Verifying insllation
  command: tail /var/log/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.log 
  register: output
  failed_when:"'Starting main loop. Accepting connections' not in output.stdout"
```

It is faling with

```
.....
 INFO Nov 10 22:57:26 [2581]: Creating child number 5 of 10 ...
 FATAL : all host have already failed
```

It seems verification had been done before tail finished.I tried with tail -f it is getting stuck there itself.

It seems some delay need to be added before tail.Help me how to add delay here.

Comment: for a really useful install tool, you'll need to include some specs about what you want in case there are errors. Will the error msgs go into the logfile? if not, then where are they going, or if no err messages even with errors, you have to have a mechanism in place to catch them. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter These points will help me in better design..I am also curious to know what kind of logic or code you will use to verify in above output..

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method to track the status of a clean install.

```
cat verifyInstall.sh

#!/bin/ksh

chkFile=$1

if [[ ! -f "$chkFile" ]] ; then
  echo "can't find file=$chkFile, can't continue" >&2
  exit 1
fi

awk '
  /Creating child number 4/{c4=1}
  /Creating child number 5/{c5=1}
  /Creating child number 6/{c6=1}
  /Creating child number 7/{c7=1}
  /Creating child number 8/{c8=1}
  /Creating child number 9/{c9=1}
  /Creating child number 10/{c10=1}
  /Finished creating all children/{fin=1}
  /Setting the various signals/{sigs=1}
  /Starting main loop. Accepting connections/{start=1}
  {
    if (c4 && c5 && c6 && c7 && c8 && c9 && c10 && fin && sigs && start) {
      print "All steps completed, done monitoring script log file=" FILENAME
      exit 0
    }
  }

  END {
    if (c4 && c5 && c6 && c7 && c8 && c9 && c10 && fin && sigs && start) {
      x=1
      # nothing to do here really, except
    }
    else {
      print "Unnexpectedly leaving script validInstall.sh, not all vars as expected, found status=" \
        "c4=" c4 " c5=" c5 " c6=" c6 " c7=" c7 " c8=" c8 " c9=" c9 " c10=" c10  \
        " fin=" fin "  sigs=" sigs  " start=" start
  exit 1
    }
  }
' "$chkFile"
```

you know of course, that once you create the file you need to make it executable with `chmod +x validInstall.sh`?

**output**

```
$ validInstall.sh tst.log
All steps completed, done monitoring script log file=tst.log
```

with a clean log file

and

```
$ validInstall.sh badTst.log
Unnexpectedly leaving script validInstall.sh, not all vars as expected, found status=c4=1 c5=1 c6= c7=1 c8=1 c9=1 c10=1 fin=1  sigs=1 start=1
```

with a copy of tst.log, where 'child number 6' was changed to 'child number 16'

Because you're using `tail -f` on the log file, I won't be able to completely match your usage.

I'm guessing you'll have other conditions that you want to trap, child number 1 ... and others. Just make a reg-exp match, and individual variable name for that case, and add it to the `&&`d list of tests in both places.

There's probably a way to make this more computer engineered using `awk`s associative arrays, but that will cost extra ;-)

This script should give you an idea on how `awk` is part of the unix tool kit and how it is used for text processing.

IHTH